# Debugging slow server response time

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, php5, debian-wheezy, response-time

I'm testing response time of my VPS server:

```
curl -s -w %{time_total}\\n -o /dev/null http://www.example.com
```

The values are typically round 300ms, Google suggests that it should be lower than 200.

Looks like this does not depend on the CMS used, the same with Wordpress and other platforms. 
Simple php pages with almost no includes have values round 175.

Maybe it's some Apache or DNS misconfiguration?
How would you debug this and see how to improve the response time?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of factors that could be contributing to this:

- DNS Lookup (how fast the DNS servers respond to your VPS)
- Network latency from your server out to the internet (how many ms it takes for a request to get through the network stack to the outside world)
- Distance latency between your VPS and the remote website (how long it takes for your request to get across the open internet from your server to the remote server)
- Network latency (again) for the remote server's network stack.
- How long the remote site takes to respond (is it a slow website? it may take time to build the page)
- The first three items after DNS lookup again in reverse order

Try pinging the remote site, or running a trace route to see where the slowdown it

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Could you please add some command line samples for each paragraph I could run to check?